# CSS hover will not work on position absolute?

Tags: css

This has never been an issue to me before, and I really don't know what's happening..

Simple - I have this css id with a picture inside.
This id has to have position: absolute for it to look correct..

But when I use position: absolute, my hover does nothing.. like i wasn't there..
When I remove the position: absolute, the hover works.

```
#pil-left {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
background-image: url(grafik/pil-left.png);
margin-left: 150px;
margin-top: 320px;
}

#pil-left:hover {
opacity: 0.6;   
}
```

That simple, but really can't get it to work.

Comment: can show an example? jsfiddle?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/RypAK/4/

Comment: It looks ok in Chrome for me too.

Comment: i tried your code on chrome as well as on firefox.It works.Check if you are hovering on the right element.Or may be if still does not work try posting complete code.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11.

Comment: works OK on chrome and ff. Remember that for IE you need to use filter: alpha(opacity=60) ; for ie5-7 and -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)"; for ie8

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unable to reproduce but had a similar issue and setting z-index has helped me.

Comment: Working perfect

Comment: Wow, i wasted few hours on this ****, thanks a lot !!

Comment: Helped me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Use z index with perspective. That will solve the issue.